# How to constraint elements in view?

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, constraints

IMPORTANT: This is not a main view but a view I added on the main one and it has its size.

I'm trying to constraint [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmuMk.png) in order to make it resizable on every iOS device. I want it to look exactly how you see it.
I followed multiple guides online but even if I do exactly what I see it doesn't seem to work for me. 
Here's what I tried:
I set the cancel's button width, then I constrained it to the view (trailing, bottom, leading) and vertically in container. I did the same for the one above it but the bottom constraint was attached to the button.

As regards the view with a lot of square buttons I:
Constrained the view to the button below it (bottom), set its width, placed it vertically in container, top space to safe area (I have a navigation bar above my view) and trailing and leading space to view.

As regards the buttons inside my view I set equal widths and hights for each of them and then I constrained them all top leading trailing and bottom (they all have a space of 7 between them or their view).

None of this works since the blue sky view either becomes bigger and wider, either goes outside of the screen, either everything gets very weird... How could I do?

Comment: What exactly you want? Are you adding multiple Buttons in your SUBVIEW?

Comment: Look at my picture, I want to constraint the buttons as you see there so that when you run the app it looks like the picture

Comment: So, for the view with buttons, you set leading, trailing and width? You should not add this width constraint.

Comment: No I set the width for the buttons, in the view I just set the height

Comment: @chestres please provide more information. can you share code?

Comment: Ok. It still difficult to represent exactly what you have done. And so to help you. Maybe you can add a diagram with all the constraint you set. And also consider using UIStackView.

Comment: You're missing some **critical** details. For instance, taking two different devices, iPhone 8 and iPhone XS Max (or even and iPad. What do you want? A resizable 6x5 grid or a static grid? Also, what's happening? Second, please, how are you defining your constraints? Can you give us something to help us duplicate the issue? Finally, a suggestion. Start smaller - say a 2x2 grid with buttons. Or even - provided you are using IB and are having a problem like this - just a simple square pink view with a single button beneath it. Get *that* working. Maybe you'll figure out the issue on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question is a bit tricky to answer. But I'll try my best :D
So, the first thing I would do is to put the pink squares inside a stackView and let autolayout help us a little. Then I would constrain the blueSkyView.top .leading and .trailing. After constrain the stackView .top, .leading, .trailing, .bottom to the blueSkyView, so that blue sky view could enlarge to fit the stack inside. 
Then constrain the buttons to the bottom, just like you made. Consider using some constraints of Greater than from blue sky to Random Color button, for example, guaranteeing they will never overlap.

Comment: How do I adjust the squares with autolayout? I already tried multiple times to put them in stack views but they become a long line

Comment: I put all the rows in different stack views and I put everything in another stack view ok?

Comment: In the each squares you set the aspect ratio to 1:1. In the stackView you can set equal spacing in distribution and set the spacing to the number you need, something like 5 or 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this view a square for very time while using different devices, you need to give a height constraint for the view and also a leading and trailing.
Then make an outlet for the height constraint. In the ***viewDidAppear*** method you should wright the below code:

```
heightConstraint.constant = myView.frame.size.width
```